# Decode URL Query String using Mod Rewrite / Regex

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, httpd, mod-proxy, regex

I have the following encoded URL

`https://example.com/external-image?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thirdpartydomain.com%2FTWM%2FImages%2F1264%2F143242%2FFull%2F2201625016119496.jpg`

I'm using mod rewrite to parse the query string and then proxy the url. The reason I'm doing this is to make non secure shared images from other third party sites secure using my own ssl.

The following code contains non encoded query parameters that work that works perfectly.

**Example URL**

`https://example.com/external-image?url=http://www.thirdpartydomain.com/TWM/Images/1264/143242/Full/2201625016119496.jpg`

**Example Code**

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+).*) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*/external-image$ %1 [P,NC,L,E=new_host:%2]

  <If "-T reqenv('new_host')">
    RequestHeader set Host %{new_host}e
  </If>
```

My goal is to encode my query parameters in the browser forming a valid url and then decode the query parameter just before I proxy the url. Anybody have any thoughts on the best way to handle this?

Comment: I would implement this with a reverse proxy, so that you assign URLs to images like `https://example.com/external-image/path/to/image`, and then Apache2 is told to proxy images from `http://thirdpartydomain.com/path/to/image`. With this approach you don't need to care about URL encoding / decoding.

Comment: @terokilkanen I'm not sure I follow you on this. I don't physically host these images on my servers, I just have references to their location in my database. Could you provide me with a little bit more detail on how you feel this should work? The only other way I could think of doing this and still keep it very dynamic was an apache query to the database using the pk of the photo record returning the photo url, but I was concerned with putting that load on the database. Anyhow I'm curious to hear a little bit more about your thoughts.

Comment: There was no information in the question that the locations are in some kind of a database. The original question was about fetching external resources whose URLs are already known, and that is easier to do with reverse proxying. Look at http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies for information on reverse proxying.

Comment: "decode the query parameter just before I proxy the url" - How were you planning to "decode the query parameter"? Then again, perhaps you don't need to and simply use the `NE` (`NOESCAPE`) flag on the `RewriteRule`? But then, what about the `new_host` env variable? OR, instead of using a query string, use _additional path info_ to pass the external URL - this is then automatically decoded by mod_rewrite/Apache. (?)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes the urls are known, but they change on a daily basis and this year alone, I have over 600 million photos pass through the system, so it's a bit of a nightmare to deal with.

Comment: @w3d So your thinking I should just pass the URLs along as a context parameter rather than a query string and mod_rewrite/apache will automatically handle the decoding?

Comment: @w3d Once I turned on AllowEncodedSlashes On  and changed my code to use context parameters, it worked perfectly.   RewriteRule .+external-image\/((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.+?\..+?)\/.+) $1 [P,NC,L,E=new_host:$2]

  <If "-T reqenv('new_host')">
    RequestHeader set Host %{new_host}e
  </If>

Comment: Good stuff. Minor point... no need to backslash escape the slashes in Apache regex (since they aren't used as delimiters).

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer so it can be formatted properly.